# How to disable/enable Sign Ups for a specific application with Auth0?

Tags: auth0

Is there a way to disable or enable sign ups for a specific application which is independent of the “Disable Sign Ups”-toggle in the dashboard for login with passwordless email (Authentication/Passwordless/Email)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out I can create another 'Tenant' (from the dashboard) with a different setting for Sign Up from the dashboard :-)

Comment: can you please elaborate? this is not very useful for people having the same question / issue

Comment: I clarified my answer a little bit. Else I recommend the Auth0 docs.

Answer (score 1):

Only partly.

It's possible via **Pre-User-Registration Hook** and/or or **Rule** with some caveats.

---

**Pre-User-Registration Hooks** :

https://auth0.com/docs/customize/hooks/extensibility-points/pre-user-registration

Something like this:

```
module.exports = function (user, context, cb) {

    return cb(new PreUserRegistrationError('Denied user registration in Pre-User Registration Hook', 'You are not allowed to register.'));
  }
};
```

Here you can just fail the registration at all times.
Problem with Hooks is that that the Pre-User-Registration Hook does not trigger for social connections / federation, only Database Connections and Passwordless.

---

Alternatively via **Rule**:

https://auth0.com/docs/customize/rules

This will always work, but the downside is that the user gets created in Auth0, they will just not be able to further proceed.

In the Rule you basically check the number of logins, if it's 0, you know that it's a new user, and block the login that follows right after user creation (signup) as well as any other time.

Example rule:
https://auth0.com/rules/disable-social-signup

Related earlier answer of mine regarding this, in the Auth0 forum:

- https://community.auth0.com/t/disable-signup-from-auth0-ui-and-enable-social-login/29227/2

Comment: Would it be possible to use a combination of environment variable (SIGN_UP_ALLOWED=false) and API (get /api/v2/users-by-email) in my login endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a custom Universal Login SPA for sign-up/in that only allows users to sign-in. Pre-registration hook to safeguard against people bypassing the UX.

Comment: Hooks only trigger for database connections though, not social connections.

Comment: If you're using social/enterprise connection can you customize the authentication UX in the federated system? What are you federating to? It's not clear in your initial question...

Comment: I'm not the OP, I'm the one who provided the answer above yours. So I don't know the use case of the OP. Maybe there isn't even any federation involed, then Hooks alone would do.
(Side-Note: I used to work at Auth0 as Solutions Engineer a while back, my answer  is based on the status as it was as of 2020.)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm using passwordless connection for a ordinary web app (not a SPA).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can configure this setting under `Authentication -> Database -> Username-Password-Authentication -> Disable Sign Ups` (you may have to scroll down a bit):

[image]

Depending on what other types of login you have configured, you may have to disable sign ups for them as well.